# MATCH AGAINST multiple words AND OR not working in codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one table like below ,table name is js_skills_achievements

```
id   skill1  skill2  skill3  skill4
1     java    php    html    android
2     php     java   jquery  html
3     sql     php    html    jquery
```

When admin search key is "java developer"

```
SELECT * FROM js_skills_achievements
WHERE MATCH(skill1,skill2,skill3,skill4) AGAINST ('java developer');
```

Its working for me , BUT I NEED MULTIPLE KEYWORDS not Working below QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM js_skills_achievements
    WHERE MATCH (js_skills_achievements.skill1,js_skills_achievements.skill2,js_skills_achievements.skill3,js_skills_achievements.skill4) AGAINST('java developer') OR (MATCH (js_skills_achievements.skill1,js_skills_achievements.skill2,js_skills_achievements.skill3,js_skills_achievements.skill4) AGAINST('php developer')

//This is Also not working
SELECT * FROM js_skills_achievements
WHERE MATCH(skill1,skill2,skill3,skill4) AGAINST ('java developer','php developer');
```

Please any one help  me.

Comment: According to the MySql documentation against takes only one String param https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Comment: Actually my Working query is SELECT * From js_skills_achievements WHERE js_skills_achievements.skill1 IN ('java developer', 'php developer') OR js_skills_achievements.skill2 IN ('java developer', 'php developer') OR js_skills_achievements.skill3 IN ('java developer', 'php developer') OR js_skills_achievements.skill4 IN ('java developer', 'php developer')

Comment: My requirement is i need to use LIKE '% java developer ,php developer %'

Comment: Is there any alternative solutions for this please ....Multiple keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM js_skills_achievements
WHERE MATCH(skill1,skill2,skill3,skill4) AGAINST ('java developer php developer');
```

[`MATCH AGAINST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) takes only 1 input. So, you can include both of the string in that 1 input.